# supertest times out on post request

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

i'm trying to use supertest to test some express routes, however the test throws a timeout error when i try to send post requests despite the get requests actually working.

this is the route i'm testing

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { command, text } = req.body;

    switch (command) {
      case 'abc': return;
      default:
        console.log('123');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

this is the test

```
describe('test', () => {
  const app: express.Express = express();
  app.use('/', route);
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  it('test', async () => {
    await request(app)
      .post('/')
      .send('command=john') 

    expect(handleSurveyListCommand).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(handleSurveyRespondCommand).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(consoleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(consoleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error('Command not found'));
  });
});
```

and this is the error thrown

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

this test fails even if the only thing i do inside the route is to log something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not responding back with the response while the request in test case is waiting for some response, instead return try sending response

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { command, text } = req.body;

    switch (command) {
      case 'abc': res.status(200).send("abc");
      default:
        res.status(200).send("123");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("unknown error");
  }
});
```

Regarding req.body undefined ->use body parsed in app

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: i feel like an idiot. i don't know why my brain froze on such trivial things.

Comment: Please check edited answer for req.body undefined issue.

Comment: i already solved the issue of undefined req.body after further inspecting the code. thanks for the help. i was calling the route before the parser.